# MSVCR100.dll is missing when running console apps

Tags: php, yii, wamp

i have installed Ampps server and Wamp server on my computer in two different drives. Now i am trying to run "yiic" on command prompt but its throwing a popup window saying that "MSVR100.dll is missing try reintalling the program to fix this problem".one thing more i would like to add is that, since i have gone through google to fix the problem of MSVCR100.dll and i have installed all the suggested files (from the microsoft website) [installed msvcr100.dll](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/52f0bd37-9a08-41b6-bb43-fa01ef3ebc4a/msvcr100dll-is-missing) but the problem still exists with me.

Comment: I think this is a WAMP issue...

Comment: Can you please elaborate so that i can get rid of this problem? Please......
Since i have installed Ampp server on the another drive of my computer  but issue remains same.

Comment: Just to be clear... you didn't have this problem before installing `Ampp`? Is your `WAMP` server sunning correctly i.e. is the icon green?

Comment: Yes sir the icon is green. And i was not having the problem before this morning. i would like to add some more information that i have tried to uninstall all the servers from my computer and i have installed again. But the problem is still alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been wondering around Google and all search engines and I came to result that the problem was in `yiic.bat` which was something like:

---

```
set YII_PATH=%~dp0

if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=php.exe

"%PHP_COMMAND%" "%YII_PATH%yiic" %*

@endlocal
```

**I changed the code to following code**

---

```
set YII_PATH=F:\wamp\www\yii\framework\

if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=F:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe

"%PHP_COMMAND%" "%YII_PATH%yiic" %*

@endlocal
```

**Which means**
please look into the `YII_PATH` to be upto `path\to\framework\`
and 
`if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND` to be upto `path\to\php.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Try installing or update Microsoft C++:

> For Windows 32 bit OS:
>
> [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)
>
> [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)
>
> For Windows 64 bit OS:
>
> [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)
>
> [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

This is a possible solution.

Comment: I have tried installing both files but i am still stuck to the problem.